# How to go to a page using a searchbar and a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I go to a page depending on what is in my search bar?
For example I want to go to "http://google.com" if my search box value is "google".
This is my html:

```
<form id="searchbox" action="">  
  <input id="search" type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="google" />  
  <button type="submit" class="search-button" onsubmit="return searchbar();">Search</button>  
</form>  
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. In the first step you should add  the code inside your "js.js" so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="searchbox" action="">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="google"  />
    <button type="submit" class="search-button" onsubmit="return searchbar();">Search</button>  
</form >

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var value = findGetParameter('search');
    switch(value){
        case 'google' : console.log('redirect'); location.href = "http://google.com"; break;
        case null : break; // First Page Load, do nothing
        default : location.href = "http://youtube.com"; break; 
    }
}
// Location Parameters
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = []; 
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        }); 
    return result;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I was also wondering if it was possible to make it go to an error page if the search was invalid (for example the only search available is "google" but you put in "youtube" for example and it goes to an error page(I would make the error page)). Thank you again, this really helped me.

Comment: Updated so that the default is there and also when it first loads it does nothing as otherwise it'll go straight to the default option. Glad to helped :-)